# My java program show 0.0 in 15/100

Tags: java

Why does this program show `0.0`?.

Below is my code:

```
   class new1{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int discount = 15;
        float discount1 = 15/100;
        System.out.println(discount1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to store 15 in float variables.

Answer (score 2):

In line   `float discount1 = 15/100;` is evaluated using the integer division.

If you want to get expected result, you should write like this

```
 float discount1 = 15.0/100;
```